# Can jaxb resolve system properties?

Tags: java, xml, properties, jaxb, unmarshalling

We use JAXB to configure object with XML. I was wondering if there is a way that JAXB could resolve system property. For instance, if I have a bean with property color, I would like to be able to do that:

```
<mybean color="${mycolor.in.data.property}" />
```

But if I do that, JAXB create the mybean object an color will be equals to the string:
`mycolor.in.data.property`

Is there is any equivalent of the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) in spring for JAXB, so that my system property could be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `XmlAdapter` is  a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) mechanism that allows you to convert an object to another object during marshalling/unmarshaller.  You could write an `XmlAdapter` that converts the system property name to the real value.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ColorAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return System.getProperty(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

}
```

Then you use the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation to configure the `XmlAdapter` for your property.

```java
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ColorAdapter.class)
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

---

**UPDATE**

> Ok thanks. Actually I do not have access to the class, as this is part
>   of an imported library. So I was more looking of a way to configure
>   this directly in the xml file, but it is probably not possible.

If you can't modify the class, then you can use a `StreamReaderDelegate` to modify the XML input.  There a few methods that deal with the text/character data so you may need to experiment to be sure that you are overriding the one that works best with the JAXB implementation you are using.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyBean.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);
        xsr = new StreamReaderDelegate(xsr) {

            @Override
            public String getText() {
                String text = super.getText();
                if(text.contains("${")) {
                    text = System.getProperty(text);
                }
                return text;
            }

        };

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually I do not have access to the class, as this is part of an imported library. So I was more looking of a way to configure this directly in the xml file, but it is probably not possible.

Comment: @Melanie - If you are using EclipseLink MOXy as your JAXB provider then you could represent the metadata as an XML document (see http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html).  Or alternatively I've updated my answer with how you could use a StAX `StreamReaderDelegate` to adjust the XML input.